# JPA JoinColumn save id external entity class inside another entity class

Tags: java, jpa, joincolumn

I have entityclass ProjectData. In this class I have UserData entity object.
I use @JoinColumn annotation to get userData when I get ProjectData- it work properly. 
But if I create new ProjectData I don't know how to save userDataId to PRJ_USER_PM_ID column;

In table PROJECT I have id of user data.
I try with additional attrbute projectUserid, but it seems to me it is not good solution.

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="PROJECT")
    public class ProjectData extends AbstractData {

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRJ_USER_PM_ID", referencedColumnName = "USR_ID",   insertable = false, updatable = false )
        UserData user;

      /*@Column(name = "PRJ_USER_PM_ID")
        Long projectUserid; */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a userData with required ID if you dont have it, and just set it to projectData:

```
projectData.setUserData (userData);
```

And then save projectData.

Comment: But I have only userID, because I set it by combobox ( where I have hashmap (id-name)). 
If I create new userData with userId it will working ?